# lodash functions are not recognizing in angular6 and jasmine test cases

Tags: jasmine, angular6, lodash

I am using lodash library in my angular application for trimming text box value.

The code am using like this
This is working fine when i run the app.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
validateForm() {
 if(_.trim(this.addusermodel.firstname) == "") {
   ////
 }
}
```

in spec file am using this code

```
describe('validateForm', () => {
    it('Form should validate', () => {   
      component.addusermodel.firstname = "wrwer";
      component.validateForm();
    });
  });
```

But when i executing the function from spec file am getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import lodash like this

`import * as _ from "lodash";` instead of `import _ from 'lodash';`